# Outdated npm dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies

I have a local machine and a server. When updating **npm** on my local, I have the following version:

```
myaccount@local:$ npm -v
3.8.5
```

But on the server:

```
myaccount@server:$ npm -v
2.1.11
```

What's more, I tried to add the `async` module to my **NodeJS** project, using `npm install --save async`, and the following dependency was added to my local:

```
{
    ...,
    "dependencies": {
      "async": "^2.0.0-rc.2",
      ...
      // Other dependencies
    }
}
```

But when I try to fetch it on my server:

```
myaccount@server:/path/to/my/project$ npm install
npm WARN package.json crypto@0.0.3 crypto is also the name of a node core module.
npm ERR! Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v0.10.41
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.11
npm ERR! code ETARGET

npm ERR! notarget No compatible version found: async@'>=2.0.0-rc.2 <3.0.0'
npm ERR! notarget Valid install targets:
npm ERR! notarget ["0.1.0","0.1.1","0.1.2","0.1.3","0.1.4","0.1.5","0.1.6","0.1.7","0.1.8","0.1.9","0.1.10","0.1.11","0.1.12","0.1.13","0.1.14","0.1.15","0.1.16","0.1.17","0.1.18","0.1.19","0.1.20","0.1.21","0.1.22","0.2.0","0.2.1","0.2.2","0.2.3","0.2.4","0.2.5","0.2.6","0.2.7","0.2.8","0.2.9","0.2.10","0.3.0","0.4.0","0.4.1","0.5.0","0.6.0","0.6.1","0.6.2","0.7.0","0.8.0","0.9.0"]
npm ERR! notarget 
npm ERR! notarget This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/certidev/apps/web-crawler/npm-debug.log
```

So, it seems my **npm** reads its dependencies in an outdated place, something like that. I'm new to **npm** and **NodeJS** so I'm not sure what's happening.

How can I fix that? I have the `npm-debug.log` file at the ready if needs be.

**EDIT:**

My **NodeJS** versions. Local:

```
myaccount@local:$ nodejs -v
v0.10.37
```

Server:

```
myaccount@server:$ nodejs -v
v0.10.41
```

Comment: Check installed Node versions on local pc and on the server: `node -v`. It seems that locally you use Node v>=5, on server v<5

Comment: But we're only talking about **npm** here aren't we? Is npm itself coded in node?

Comment: Have you installed npm on local pc manually? It's installed with node automaticly, and for node version v0.10.x it can't be v3.x. (npm 3.x has added only in Node.js v5.x). If so, remove locally installed Node version and install v0.10.41.

Comment: It was first installed automatically, but seeing that problem I did a manual update on both my local and the server, thinking it could solve the issue.

Comment: Remove locally installed Node, and install it again. And never update npm manually.